# lua luaL_checkstring() doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, c, lua, arduino, esp32

i use latest lua 5.4.4 on esp32 arduino.
All work fine on oldest Arduino version 1.0.6 but after upgrading to version 2.0.3, the **luaL_checkstring()** function began to work incorrectly.

my c++ code:

```cpp
static int lua_wrapper_myfunc(lua_State *L) {
  const char *Value= luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
  ...
  return 0;
}

...

lua_register(L, "myfunc", lua_wrapper_myfunc);
```

my lua code:

```lua
myfunc(123)
```

If as a parameter of a custom function I pass strings, a boolean value, a floating-point number, then everything is fine, but if I pass an **integer**, then the **luaL_checkstring()** function always returns the text value "ld".

what could be the problem?

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: If you want to return a value back to Lua, push it and then `return 1`.

Comment: Thank you, I know that and there is no problem with that.